# Why django ManytoManyField don't save some models?

Tags: python, django

Below is my `models.py`.

```py
class Report(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40, default = "-")
    favorite = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='Fav', related_name='favorite_reports') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
class Fav(models.Model) :
    
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='favs_users')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('report', 'user')

    def __str__(self) :
        return '%s likes %s'%(self.user.username, self.report.company_name[:10])
```

Below is `views.py`

```py
    def post(self, request, pk) :  
        t = Report.objects.get(id = pk)
        fav = Fav(user=request.user, report=t)
        try:
            fav.save()  # In case of duplicate key
            print(request.user.favorite_reports) #home.Report.None 
            print('t =', t.favorite) # t = auth.User.None
            print('fav =',fav.report, fav.user) # fav = untitle hello1
            print('uesr =',request.user, request.user.favorite_reports,request.user.favs_users) #uesr = hello1 home.Report.None home.Fav.None
        except IntegrityError as e:
            pass
        return redirect('home:homepage')
```

I want to show different button color to user whether user fav some report or not. So I checked `request.user.favorite_reports` and `request.user.favs_users` after I save `Fav` but it return `home.Report.None home.Fav.None`

But When I print `fav.report, fav.user` It returns well. Why this happened?

How can I check `user` `Fav` some `report` in `template`?

like `{% if report.company_name in  user.favorite_reports  %}` But It dosen't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `request.user.favorite_reports.all()`

Comment: Then, In html How can I get all user.favorite_reports??
`{{ user.favorite_reports.all() }}` get error and `{{ user.favorite_reports.all}} return `home.Report.None`

Comment: M2M field is creating join table to represent this relationship between two objects, so when you want to get all objects from that table you have to do .all() or you can filter it by other model field. In django templates a lot such work is done for you, for example you don't need to call .all() on M2M to get all rows